# How to get my Ubuntu server a domain name

Tags: ubuntu, dns, apache-http-server, domain-name

I just got my Ubuntu server up and running on ssh:22 and apache:8. Everything is working inside and outside my home network, and I'm ready to assign a domain name.

Now I am wondering if anyone knows the cheapest (hopefully free) way to do this. So the end result I want is: not having to go to `http://68.0.0.0` but going to http://example.com instead.

Comment: http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/registerdomain.shtml

Comment: You will have to purchase a registered domain name. Your clients won't be able to resolve your hostname in any other way. Unless you tell every of them to modify their hosts file, which would be very funny. However, there are some free domain name providers, but you won't probably get a decent name that way. If you want only hosts in your local network to be able to access it via name and not IP, you can set-up a local DNS server

Answer (score 1):

If you want a free solution, you can use Dynamic DNS for example www.noip.com. But with a 'free' solution, comes a catch: Your hostname will be something like "myserver.no-ip.info" rather than something nice like "myserver.com" or whatever you like.

Those you will need to register for a hostname and pay for it.

And after that comes the next step of allowing incoming connection on your home gateway and redirect the incoming request to your Ubuntu Server (Port Forwarding)